# Why don't I have the latitude and longitude lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is from: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{% 
\pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)} 
\pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}} 
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
\pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2}
\pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} 
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
\pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2}
\pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} 
\tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(3,0)}}}}

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
\LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
\tikzset{current plane/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,     (3,\cosEl*\sint)}}}
\tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={xscale=\R,yscale=\RR}}

\pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{tan(#2)*tan(\angEl)} 
 % angle of "visibility"
\pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}  
 \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1); 
 \draw[current plane,dashed,black!80] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-        \angVis:\angVis:1);
  }
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
\tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={xscale=\R,yscale=\RR}}
% angle of "visibility" 
\pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
 \draw[current plane,black] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1); 
\draw[current plane,dashed,thick,black] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1); 
 }


\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2}
\def\RR{1.6} 
\def\angEl{15}
%\filldraw[ball color=gray!10] (6,0) circle[x radius=\R, y radius=\RR];
\foreach \t in {-80,-70,...,80} { \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {-5,-35,...,-175} { \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you use `preview` and `standalone` together like that? It doesn't seem a good idea....

Comment: Thanks cfr. Your suggestion fix the porblem. Yes, maybe my question is question is duplicate. Can I m erase it?